# Accessing attributes of nodes in a loop

Tags: python, networkx

I have the following list of nodes.  I want to get the longitude and latitude of each node.

```
('11', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -31.93333, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 11, 'Longitude': 115.83333, 'label': u'Perth1'})
('10', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -35.28346, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 10, 'Longitude': 149.12807, 'label': u'Canberra2'})
('13', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -34.93333, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 13, 'Longitude': 138.6, 'label': u'Adelaide1'})
('12', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -31.93333, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 12, 'Longitude': 115.83333, 'label': u'Perth2'})
('15', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -37.814, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 15, 'Longitude': 144.96332, 'label': u'Melbourne1'})
('14', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -34.93333, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 14, 'Longitude': 138.6, 'label': u'Adelaide2'})
('17', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -23.7, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 17, 'Longitude': 133.88333, 'label': u'Alice Springs'})
('16', {'Internal': 1, 'Latitude': -37.814, 'Country': u'Australia', 'id': 16, 'Longitude': 144.96332, 'label': u'Melbourne2'})
```

I know  accessing like

```
G.nodes['11']['longitude']
G.nodes['10']['longitude']
G.nodes['13']['longitude'].
```

But I want flexible access which means no need to change the code if the number of nodes increases.  How can I do that?

Comment: the format of your nodes in your list doesn't match the way you're accessing them, can you fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate through the nodes.  The "best" way to iterate through the nodes is with `G.nodes_iter()` (a generator), but alternately you could use `G.nodes()` (a list):

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node('11', longitude = 3)
for node in G.nodes_iter():
   print G.node[node]['longitude']
> 3
G.add_node('3', longitude = 5)
for node in G.nodes_iter():
    print G.node[node]['longitude']
>3
>5
```

If you care about the order that you go through the list, you'll want to use `G.nodes()` and sort it appropriately.

---

Note --- in your example you had `G.nodes[][]`.  That won't work.  It should be `G.node[][]`.

Answer (score 3):

The most compact way to iterate nodes is as follows:

```
for i in G:
    G.node[i]['longitude']
```